# Only keep last instance of RegEx Match

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text document that contains the following text

```
Searching at 2016-04-25 12:35:00
Searching at 2016-04-25 12:40:00
Searching at 2016-04-25 12:45:00
    Found Data
Searching at 2016-04-25 12:50:00
Searching at 2016-04-25 12:55:00
    Found Data
```

I am trying to use Notepad++ to remove all lines with `Searching...` unless there is data immediately after.

I am currently using Notepad++ to replace all instances of `Searching.*?$\r\n(Searching.*?)` with `$1`. However I need to push `Replace All` several times depending on the # of consecutive times it searches without finding data.

In the example above, the desired output is:

```
Searching at 2016-04-25 12:45:00
    Found Data
Searching at 2016-04-25 12:55:00
    Found Data
```

Is there a way to this in Notepad++ using RegEx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern

```
(?:Searching.*?$\r\n)+(Searching.*?\r\n)
```

and replace it with `$1`

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
/Searching.*$\n(?!\s*Found Data)/
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vY2wU1/2)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `Searching.+\R(?=Searching)`
- Replace with: `NOTHING`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Check `Regular expresssion` but **not** `dot matches newline`.
This will replace every searching line followed by another searching line.

`\R` stands for any kind of linebreak.
`(?=Searching)` is a positive lookahead that make sure we have the word `Searching` after the linebreak.